# Generate YouTube Thumbnails from HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, youtube

I'm trying to get the thumbnails from Youtube and insert the corresponding image into the html.

My HTML:

```
<div id="first">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dzpkn29_vY"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFCRMonf7lI"></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps-9L0-NO"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJZCHZ2wV7U"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I'd like the HTML to look like this:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBTUAHGpQqE">
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/-dzpkn29_vY/2.jpg" alt="#" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTkPfjSXFpo">
      <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/xFCRMonf7lI/2.jpg" alt="#" />
    </a>
 </li>
```

Is there anyway I can use this function I found on SO:

```
function getScreen( url, size ) {
  if(url === null){ return ""; }

  size = (size === null) ? "big" : size;
  var vid;
  var results;

  results = url.match("[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)");

  vid = ( results === null ) ? url : results[1];

  if(size == "small"){
    return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+vid+"/2.jpg";
  } else {
    return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+vid+"/0.jpg";
  }
}
```

Edit: The problem is dynamically adding the img based off each a href

Comment: so what is the problem? you dont know how to add the tag img inside the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo that gives you the desired result.

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwelch/7aJTx/)

`Each` will loop through all of the links within the selection set. To set the value you need to use the `html` function. Returning the string from the function with its wrapping will set the images onto the page.

Comment: you won me! I was doing the same but slower!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't easy to find a simple answer.

But I finally could come up with something that could work with dynamic youtube iframes.

Here you go: [a link] (http://jsfiddle.net/9jgQU/)!

```
var iframeSrc = $('#idFrame').attr('src');
var url = iframeSrc;
url = url.split("/");
$("#la").attr("src",'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+url[4]+'/mqdefault.jpg');
```